# Grouped Products "Show All" Button

Tags: catalog, products, product-list, grouped-products, magento-2.1.9

I am currently working on my website, Magento 2.1.9. I have created a grouped product and now trying to figure out how to configure the number of products shown. How do I display only 5 products and add "show all" button?
Please help. Thanks!
[image: Canvas Screenshot]